# Regressive python counter

Tags: python, formatting, console-application

i was doing a small weekend project, kind of a music player, in python (console). I'm done in all the part of selecting music, parsing ID3 tags, playing and blablabla. I just think i need something like a counter to show the music's total time and played time.

Basically what i need is to print a string, erase **only** that string and print it again. I don't care if i need any external libraries for this, but i need it to be windows if exists.

So, is there any way to do this on python?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at the curses module which provides more control over the console. It is built into python.

**EDIT**

Apparently the standard library curses isn't available on Window, but you can look at using this: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#curses

But a simpler strategy is to use "\b" it is a backspace character.

```
sys.stdout.write("a\b")
```

Has no output because the a is erase. You might be able to use that.

Comment: The curses module doesn't support Windows.

Comment: @interjay, curses! didn't know that.